# how find out Sass version used in Node-Sass package on Node with terminal

Tags: node.js, sass, node-modules, node-sass

Need to know sass lib version delivered by Node-Sass package in Node console

Since lib version may differ from the one at github i want to check it with a line of code in the terminal

> Since node-sass >=v3.0.0 LibSass version is determined at run time.

Answer (score 3):

So here it's after long searching

`node -e 'console.log(require("node-sass").info)'`